# how to transfer mails from merak to exchange

Tags: email, exchange

I have a Merak mail server that include about 500 email accounts.on the other hand I've got Exchange mail server with about 500 email accounts.the user accounts in both mail server are the same .I wanna omit Merak mail server .but before that I should transfer all user's messages from their Merak account into their exchange account.

whats the best solution .How to transfer messages from Merak to Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news but this is a horrible migration, I completed one not too long ago and after building my Exchange 2010 infrastructure side by side with Merak as POC I ended up doing quite a manual migration.

In the end I had to get outlook setup for Marek users as IMAP, export to PST, import to Exchange Mail account.

My migration was about 150 users so I perform this over a number of days doing around 8-10 users a day (export running overnight).

Any other help let me know,

Charles

Comment: please.help.I gotta do that

Comment: Where are you at the moment with your Exchange environment?

Comment: any answer ????

Comment: Any answer to what?